# dhcpcd fallback triggering even when lease offered by DHCP server

Tags: raspbian, dhcp

In /etc/dhcpcd.conf on my `Raspberry Pi` I have:

```
# fallback to static profile on eth0
profile static_eth0
static ip_address=192.168.60.100/24
static routers=192.168.60.250
static domain_name_servers=192.168.60.250

interface eth0
fallback static_eth0
```

However, I am always receiving the fallback address even when a `DHCP` address is available.

Running dhcpcd manually, this is what I see:

```
$sudo dhcpcd -B -d -w -4 eth0
dhcpcd-8.1.2 starting
eth0: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' PREINIT
eth0: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' CARRIER
eth0: delaying IPv4 for 0.8 seconds
eth0: using ClientID 01:b8:27:eb:22:1c:05
eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
eth0: sending DISCOVER (xid 0x274915b3), next in 3.4 seconds
eth0: sending DISCOVER (xid 0x274915b3), next in 7.7 seconds
eth0: offered 192.168.10.220 from 192.168.10.1
eth0: sending REQUEST (xid 0x274915b3), next in 3.3 seconds
eth0: selected profile static_eth0
eth0: using ClientID 01:b8:27:eb:22:1c:05
eth0: using static address 192.168.60.100/24
eth0: adding IP address 192.168.60.100/24 broadcast 192.168.60.255
eth0: adding route to 192.168.60.0/24
eth0: adding default route via 192.168.60.250
eth0: ARP announcing 192.168.60.100 (1 of 2), next in 2.0 seconds
eth0: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' STATIC
eth0: ARP announcing 192.168.60.100 (2 of 2)
```

Note the offer of a `DHCP` address from 192.168.10.1 but the selection of the fallback anyway.

What is going on here? And how do I stop it?

If I remove the fallback line from `dhcpcd.conf` the `DHCP` address that's offered is accepted without any issues.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced a similar problem (dhcpcd falls back to the static profile after soliciting an IP from a DHCP server) and though I don't have a solution yet, I found the reason for it:

My system time is not maintained while switched off (it usually gets the time from a NTP server). If the last DHCP lease expires while switched off, on the next restart the system time lags behind and it falls back directly to the static profile. As there is no NTP server that can be reached with the static IP, the system is stuck in this state.